# extracting column name and using it to output filename

Tags: shell, awk, sed, perl

```
#chr    fivep   threep  strand  sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 name1   name2
chrI    9442    9492    +   0   0   0   0   na  na
chrI    12584   12631   +   0   0   0   0   na  na
chrI    12584   12679   +   16  16  15  22  na  na
chrI    12584   12727   +   0   0   0   0   na  na
chrI    12632   12679   +   13  12  16  9   na  na
```

I have a file in the above format. I want output such that I get 4 individual files as output name which are basically the columns sample1 , sample2 etc.

As an example, this is what I want to do:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$9":"$10,$5,$4}' > sample1.txt
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$9":"$10,$6,$4}' > sample2.txt
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$9":"$10,$7,$4}' > sample3.txt
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$9":"$10,$8,$4}' > sample4.txt
```

I can do this for few columns but I have a large file with many columns. How can I do this in a loop fashion so that I don't have to type every awk statement individually

Comment: Are those columns actually named as `sample<number>` ?

Comment: No, I named it here for the purpose of showing a file, but they are different in names

Comment: Write a shell function, e.g.

`e(){ awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$9":"$10,$'$(($1+4))',$4}' > simple$1.txt ; }`

and invoke it as `e 1`, `e 2` etc. You can then put this in a loop, e.g. for ((i=1;i<5;i++)) ; do e $i ; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a for-loop (`ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`):

```
for ((i=5;i<=8;i++)); do
  awk -v i="$i" -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{fname=$i".txt"}{print $1,$2,$3,$9":"$10,$i,$4 > fname}' infile
done
```

Start and end fields are given in the `for`-loop. The output filename is extracted from the header line with appended suffix `.txt` and the redirection is done in `awk`.